# How can I convert a single Unicode value out of mb_convert_encoding into integer number

Tags: php, php-5.6

In PHP,
How can I convert the Unicode value out of mb_convert_encoding into integer number

```
$A = mb_convert_encoding('و',"UTF-8");
```

> `$A = 'و'`;

I need to convert `'و'` to `1608` which is the decimal equivalent of `'و'`

Answer (score 2):

You want [`mb_ord()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php). `mb_ord()` gives you the code point of a unicode character and [`mb_chr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php) is the inverse.

```
<?php
$A = 'و';
echo mb_ord($A); // 1608
echo mb_chr(1608); //و
```

There's a php5 [polyfill on the man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#42778) if you can't use php7. I modified it slightly from the one on the man page.

```
if (!function_exists('mb_ord')) {
    function mb_ord($u) {
        $k = mb_convert_encoding($u,"UTF-8");
        $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
        $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
        return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work in PHP less than 7, is there another way ?

Comment: I tested it my php5.6 installation and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine in all PHP 5, PHP 7

```
 $ret = mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UTF-32BE', 'UTF-8');
 return hexdec(bin2hex($ret));
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution for php5 than the one I posted +1